# Losing selecteditem when clicking on a empty space in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to ask you something, I have a listbox which contains multiple items. 
The listbox is set to MultiSimple as SelectionMode. So I can select multiple items.

It's working perfectly but if I click on a empty space in my listbox it causes to deselect the last item I selected. Or when there is no item selected it selects the first item.

How can I prevent the listbox to select/deselect items when I click on a empty space?
(With the empty space I mean the space right under my items.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I recreated exactly what you did and the only option I came up with is trying to make you listbox smaller to eliminate white space. If the list in the box isn't a fixed size you could always make its size change based on the list size and set a maximum size before you need to scroll through it.

It's not the greatest solution but it seems to work.

It would look something like this.

```
public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
            if (listBox1.Items.Count < 6)
            {

                listBox1.Height = listBox1.Items.Count*12+9;
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Height = 69;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this version of the ListBox control:

```
public class ListEx : ListBox {
  private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
  protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
      Point pt = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
      if (this.IndexFromPoint(pt) == -1) {
        return;
      }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

Converted from [multisimple listbox. stop whitespace clicking from selecting deselecting last clicked item](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a53a6cb-ec05-4ba0-9070-ffbbc372e245/multisimple-listbox-stop-whitespace-clicking-from-selecting-deselecting-last-clicked-item)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The code is a little too advanced for me the soloution above works great. Your answer should work too I think I've seen the same sort of solution for listviews.